# Proving that an increasing iterative sequence increases at a decreasing rate

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, inequalities

In this question
[Proving a sequence of integrals increases (iterated minimax distributions)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80084/proving-a-sequence-of-integrals-increases-iterated-minimax-distributions)

Pietro Majer proved that

$$\int_0^1F_n(x)  dx \leq \int_0^1F_{n+1}(x) dx$$ when $$F_n(x) = (1-(1-F_{n-1}(x))^c)^c$$ and $F_0(x) = x$ and  $n$ and $c$ are integers, $n\geq 1$ and $c \geq 2$$

In other words, that the sequence $\int_0^1F_n(x)dx$ increases with $n$.

I would really like to also be able to show that the sequence increases at a strictly decreasing rate:  i.e. that
$$\int_0^1F_{n+2}(x)  dx - \int_0^1F_{n+1}(x) dx < \int_0^1F_{n+1}(x)  dx - \int_0^1F_{n}(x) dx $$

Can anyone help me out?  I wasn't sure if it was more appropriate to add comments in the original question, or to start a new question.  Hopefully I made the right call.  Thank you!

Comment: Hi Jennifer, have you tried the analog computation as in the other question?